# How to listen to a stream only once in a stateful flutter widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, lifecycle

This stateful widget is attached to a tab bar.

The first time it appears, it successfully listens to the stream.

But when I tap on another tab and tap again on the radar tab, I get the  `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.` error message.

Here are the logs:

```
flutter: init state radar: stream subscription is null
flutter: init state radar: stream subscription
flutter: init state radar: stream subscription is null
flutter: init state radar: stream subscription
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
```

I wonder

1. why dispose is never called,
2. why the subscription is no permitted in the state either.

How should I handle this use case?

```dart
/// The gas station screen
class GasStationRadarScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  GasStationRadarScreen({required Key key, required this.title})
      : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _GasStationRadarScreenState createState() => _GasStationRadarScreenState();
}


class _GasStationRadarScreenState extends State<GasStationRadarScreen> {
  /// The gas stations list to be shown
  GasStationsList _gasStations = [];

  /// The sbscription to the stream
  StreamSubscription? _gasStationsListSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    print(
        'init state radar: stream subscription is $_gasStationsListSubscription');

    /// The stream controller that brings the gas stations list whenever it changes
    if (_gasStationsListSubscription == null) {
      print('init state radar: stream subscription');

      _gasStationsListSubscription =
          GasStationRadar.shared.streamController.stream.listen((gasStations) {
        setState(() {
          _gasStations = gasStations;
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('disposing radar: cancelling subscription');

    // == Stop listening the stream
    _gasStationsListSubscription?.cancel();
    _gasStationsListSubscription = null;

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried exposing it as a `asBroadcastStream`?

Comment: You should use `StreamBuilder` instead of managing it by yourself in a `StatefulWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by createing:

```dart
  /// The stream controller that pushes gas stations list whenever the vehicle moves
  StreamController<GasStationsList> streamController =
      StreamController<GasStationsList>.broadcast();
```

My code then becomes:

```dart
/// The gas station radar singleton that holds the broadcast stream controller
class GasStationRadar {
   StreamController<GasStationsList> streamController =
      StreamController<GasStationsList>.broadcast();
}


/// The stateful widget that subscribes to the stream

class _GasStationRadarScreenState extends State<GasStationRadarScreen> {
  /// The gas stations list to be shown
  GasStationsList _gasStations = [];


  /// The subscription to the stream
  StreamSubscription? _gasStationsListSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    print(
        'init state radar: stream subscription is $_gasStationsListSubscription');

    /// The stream controller that brings the gas stations list whenever it changes
    if (_gasStationsListSubscription == null) {
      print('init state radar: stream subscribe');

      _gasStationsListSubscription =
          GasStationRadar.shared.streamController.stream.listen((gasStations) {
        setState(() {
          _gasStations = gasStations;
        });

      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('disposing radar: cancelling subscription');

    // == Stop listening the stream
    _gasStationsListSubscription?.cancel();
    _gasStationsListSubscription = null;

    super.dispose();
  }
```